# ¿Cómo optimizar y reducir al mínimo el uso de datos de una aplicación?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Buen día tengan todos!

Quisiera su asesoría en base a su experiencia en el manejo de base de datos. Tengo un sistema web con una base de datos de 350,000 registros aprox. con múltiples columnas.

Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo optimizar y reducir al mínimo el uso de datos de esta aplicación? Es decir, para que la petición de datos se reduzca al mínimo por parte del sistema. Teniendo en cuenta que algunos usuarios la usen con datos móviles, además de que no se cuelgue en la espera de consultas.

Quisiera su asesoría, técnicas, métodos, herramientas, infraestructura, etc..

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Exáctamente cómo esperas que alguien pueda responder a eso para una aplicación y unos requerimientos completamente desconocidos? Y en todo caso la optimización de aplicaciones requiere de un conocimiento a fondo de la aplicación y de constante medición y prueba de los resultados, todo lo cual da para preguntas muchos más abiertas de lo que permite este sitio (que, como habrás leido el [help] y el [ask], pide que se hagan preguntas **específicas** que puedan tener una solución correcta, y no un montón de vagas indicaciones).

Comment: Una asesoría no exige una respuesta concreta sino un consejo. Un asesor es un consejero, el que ilustra. Da un panorama y emite una opinión. Es muy diferente a una serie de pasos secuencial de lo que se debe hacer.

Comment: Lamento que se halla malinterpretado mi pregunta. Comparto una respuesta a mi propia pregunta: [Ver artículo](https://blog.arsys.es/como-optimizar-bases-de-datos-mysql/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si la aplicación la has hecho tu lo ideal es utilizar las tecnologías **XML+XSLT**. O podrías utilizar de forma similar también JSON+Javascript para generar el contenido HTML vía DOM, pero es mucho más costoso que hacerlo con XSLT.

XML+XSLT no es muy conocido por desgracia pero optimiza mucho los datos que se envían por parte del servidor al navegador.

Ya que lo único dinámico (lo que cambia) es el XML que generas en PHP, el cual contiene los datos (por ejemplo nombre de artículo, precio, descripción, ....).

Todo lo demás que se repite siempre en una web (cabeceras del html, menús, pie, ...) se puede pasar a una plantilla XSLT, éstas son siempre las mismas y no cambian, por lo que el navegador no las vuelve a descargar cada vez al tenerlas cacheadas. Además trasladas la fusión del XML con la plantilla al navegador, por lo que quitas faena al servidor.

XSLT son plantillas que se aplican al XML, más o menos igual que el CSS al respecto de HTML, pero las plantillas XSLT tienen cosas bastante avanzadas como bucles (for), matchs (para cada elemento xml hacer algo), sentencias if, sentencias switch(case), ....

Esta tecnología se puede aplicar a toda la página web, o aplicar solamente a la carga de resultados de una búsqueda, página de artículos, etc.

Hay varias opciones:

- Tienes una web normal en PHP que genera HTML, con su CSS, Javascript. Modificas la parte de las búsquedas de la web (las páginas de resultados de las búsquedas) las pasas a AJAX, dicho AJAX obtendrá el XML con los datos y luego mediante Javascript aplicarás la plantilla XSLT correspondiente con el objeto de JavaScript `XSLTProcessor`.
- Otra opción más compleja es que tus páginas sean realmente XML generado por PHP, al que el navegador le aplica el XSLT directamente (se utiliza una cabecera en el XML al estilo el `<style>` de HTML. Obviamente te obliga a programar toda la web con plantillas XSLT que dependiendo de la complejidad de la misma puede ser bastante complejo de realizar.

Te dejo unos enlaces para que veas un poco su funcionamiento:

Aplicando plantillas XSLT mediante Javascript
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_client.asp

http://www.mclibre.org/consultar/xml/lecciones/xml_xslt.html

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp